# Android - Launch "Facebook Work Chat" Application from other application

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking, url-scheme, facebook-workplace

I would like to open the “Workplace Chat by Facebook” application ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.workchat ) via URL like the Facebook app does.

For example: When I try to open "fb://page/" inside my custom application, it will launch the Facebook app from my device (if installed).

So I would like to know the URL of the Workplace Chat application.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run another application (like Workplace), you can use it's package name and launch it if it exists like below.

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.workchat");
if (launchIntent != null) { 
    startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```